# Shadow beneath Actionbar-compat while using paddings

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'm working on an Android application which uses the compatibility package from Google for getting fragments and such in Android 2.x. The actionbar has been created based on Google's example. A white "shadow" has been put beneath it using

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/actionbar_shadow</item>
```

However the object below the actionbar (a fragment) contains a ListView with the following property

```
android:paddingTop="5dp"
```

This results in the white shadow also dropping 5dp:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the padding on the ListView while keeping the shadow in it's proper place?

Comment: Why is the padding there? Can you post the full XML? I suspect it's the padding.

Comment: Yes as Matthew said, could you please share your xml? and as an alternative put android:layout_marginTop to your list which will push your first item in the list 5dips below the bar.

Comment: Have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This item should be in the app theme not the ActionBar style.